# No instance for (Num a0) arising from a use of ‘it’

Tags: haskell

I have following code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, FlexibleInstances #-}

type VersionCompound = Maybe Int

class VersionOperations a where
    decrement :: a -> a

instance VersionOperations VersionCompound where
        decrement Nothing = Nothing
        decrement (Just 0) = Just 0
        decrement (Just num) = Just (num - 1)
```

When I try to run command `decrement (Just 5)`, I get following error:

```
<interactive>:8:1:
    No instance for (Num a0) arising from a use of ‘it’
    The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Num Data.Attoparsec.Internal.Types.Pos
        -- Defined in ‘Data.Attoparsec.Internal.Types’
      instance Integral a => Num (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      instance Num Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
      ...plus five others
    In the first argument of ‘print’, namely ‘it’
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: `decrement (Just 5) :: VersionCompound` should give it the info it needs to compile. You should really be using a `newtype` though.

Comment: `decrement (Just (5 :: Int))` is an other way to make it compile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ghc is saying that it cannot infer what type to use. If you run `:t decrement (Just 5)`, you will see that it has type `(Num a, VersionOperations (Maybe a)) => Maybe a`.

We can see that there is only one value of "a" that satisfies this currently, but Ghc cannot. Indeed, if someone were to add an instance such as `instance VersionOperations (Maybe Float) where` somewhere else in the program, it would become truly ambiguous.

The easiest solution is to just add an explicit type signature. `decrement (Just 5) :: Maybe Int` should work.